# Get timestamp from one table (displayed on different rows) and display it in my query

Tags: sql

I am trying to write SQL where there is a table which has different timestamps for when the order status changes from one status to another. I need to capture those timestamps and display it in my SQL output.

If I use the join command it gives me 6 different rows where all the information is same but different timestamps for different order statuses when it changed. Is there a way to capture these different time stamps and display it as my SQL output.

As a simple example order changed from DC Allocated to Packed on 12/15/2019 10:00 AM and then from Packed to Shipped on 12/15/2019 12:00 PM
I need to show this as:

[image: SQL Output]

Currently I am getting 2 rows with the same data but different timestamps for Packed and Shipped statuses. There are multiple tables in play here but Order table gives the order number and status table gives the transaction status and time whenever the order was updated by the processor.

Comment: SQL Server? MySQL? Or PostgresSQL? You aren't using all 3 right?

Comment: could you add the SQL query you're using?

Comment: Actually it was better when you had your data in text, images are not preferred on SO. Why did you change it?

Comment: Please show us sample data *and* expected results as tabular text.

Comment: I've removed the overlapping RDBMS tags... please add back the one of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The basic pattern for this is to aggregate over a conditional expression, eg

```
select OrderNumber,
       max(case when Status = 'Packed' then StatusDate else null end) Packed,
       max(case when Status = 'Shipped' then StatusDate else null end) Shipped
from OrderStatus
group by OrderNumber
```